# What are the .skse files created alongside my saves for?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

Whenever I save a game, SKSE seems to create a file with the same name and the .skse extension alongside it. Do these files hold any useful information, or are they some sort of debug output? I'm asking because Skyrim doesn't create backup copies of these files when backing up overwritten quick and autosaves (quicksave.ess.bak, autosave#.ess.bak).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These files save the persistent data of mods created with the [Skyrim Script Extender](http://skse.silverlock.org/) that need to save extra data not part of the standard save file.

Comment: I see. Is there any way to find out which mods are writing to these files without going over each mod, so I can figure out what I'll lose if I'm forced to revert to a .bak save?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I've never tried dissecting a skse save file.